# Launch a background process and check when it ends

Tags: bash

How can I launch a process in background and check when it ends within a bash script? 
My idea is a script like this:

```
launch backgroundprocess &
while [ Process is running ];do
   echo "PROCESS IS RUNNING\r"
done;

echo "PROCESS TERMINATED"
```

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: How to wait in bash for several subprocesses to finish, and return exit code !=0 when any subprocess ends with code !=0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/356100/4561887)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The key is the "wait" command:

```
#!/bin/bash

/my/process &
/another/process &
wait
echo "All processes done!"
```

Comment: Benefit of this: it does NOT burn CPU time with an infinite loop running all the time.... ;)

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that you can't do anything else while you are waiting, such as indicating progress to the user. Only [cuonglm's solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76720/6403) allows you to do this.

Comment: @Mark Booth You can indicate progress with a third asynchronous job.  eg: `cmd1 & p=$!; cmd2 & q=$!; while sleep 1; do echo still running ; done& wait $p $q; kill $!;`

Answer (score 52):

With `wait` you can have the granularity you need:

```
sleep 1 &
PID1=$!
sleep 2 &
PID2=$!

wait $PID1
echo 'PID1 has ended.'
wait
echo 'All background processes have exited.'
```

Answer (score 46):

Here is one way to do it:

```
launch backgroundprocess &
PROC_ID=$!

while kill -0 "$PROC_ID" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
    echo "PROCESS IS RUNNING"
done
echo "PROCESS TERMINATED"
exit 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely the only answer which answers my interpretation of the original question (and the reason why I ended up looking at this question)

Comment: @cuonglm, What is there are multiple processes? Probably `wait` is more suitable for that?

Comment: @cuonglm what does -0 option to kill command do

Comment: @k_vishwanath it report whether process is still running or not.

Comment: how would you capture/know the exit status of the process when it terminates ?

Comment: Is there a chance of a race condition?

Answer (score 1):

`wait` only works for a child process launched in the same shell; it's a shell function after all.

For any arbitrary background process you need to work with PID. What nobody here mentions is kernel *PID recycling*. Modern linux systems may reuse PID quite often depending on the load. **You need more than just PID to reliably identify the process.** One simple approach is to save the time when the process started and compare it regularly with the current process start time. Should PID be recycled its start time will not be the same.

Process start time is reported as field 22 in [/proc/[pid]/stat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) file. The time is measured in [jiffies](https://elinux.org/Kernel_Timer_Systems) (at most 10ms) which provides enough precision to detect process ID recycling.

```
PID=<process ID>
START_TIME=$(cut -d ' ' -f 22 /proc/$PID/stat)

while [ "$(cut -d ' ' -f 22 /proc/$PID/stat 2>/dev/null)" = "$START_TIME" ]; do
    echo "PROCESS IS RUNNING"
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your process with nohup and write shell script to read nohup.out file which nohup uses to log .

```
  nohup command &
```

Comment: (1) At the risk of splitting hairs, `nohup` doesn't write anything to `nohup.out`; it merely *creates* the file, and redirects the output of the command to it.  (2) If the command doesn't produce any output, nothing will be written to `nohup.out`, and this idea goes nowhere fast.  (3) Even if *`command`* does write output, how can you tell when it ends by monitoring that output?

Comment: @G-Man maybe by checking the output of `lsof` to see if `nohup` is still using `nohup.out`, but I agree this is a very hairy method.

Comment: (4) By the time *`command`* starts running, `nohup` is gone. (1) Yes, I’m repeating a number, because I’m repeating what I said two years ago: `nohup` doesn’t write anything to `nohup.out`. (5) Yes, you could write a shell script to loop and run `lsof` to see whether `nohup.out` is still open. But that would be a different answer. (6) Even if you did that, it would be unreliable. What if some other process opened the `nohup.out` file? You’d really want to check if this specific process had `nohup.out` open. (7) But, if you’re going to do that, why not just check whether the process is running?